# Angular2,Typescript: array map() method: Pushing nested elements. Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Hi in Angular 4 I'm using the following code to parse data from an API to TypeScript array of rows. The code below works if elements ['item.tceCampRun', 'item.tceCommTreeDetail'] exist.

If one of them like element item.tceCommTreeDetail does not exist I get this ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined.

What is the best way to process a nested object like this?

```
 private handleGetCamp(data: Response) {
    if (data.status === 200) {
      // this.tceCamp = data.json();
      // this.firstTceCamp = this.tceCamp[0];

      let other = []; // your other array...
      let j = 1;
      let run = 999000;
      let runheader = true;
      let runheaderid = 1;

      data.json().map(item => {
          j++;
          runheader = true;
          return {
              id: j,
              rowtype: 'camp',
              expanded: false,
              cells: [{ cid: 1, text: item.name }, { cid: 2, text: item.dailyStartTime }, { cid: 3, text: item.dailyEndTime }, { cid: 4, text: item.scriptId }, { cid: 14 }],
              rows:[{
                id: run++,
                pid: j,
                header: true,
                rowtype: 'run',
                expanded: false,
                cells: [{cid: 1, text: 'Runs', header: false},
                  {cid: 2, text: 'Created', header: true},
                  {cid: 3, text: 'Modified', header: true},
                  {cid: 4, text: 'Camp', header: true},
                  {cid: 12, text: ' ', header: true},
                  {cid: 13, text: ' ', header: true}],
                rows:
                  item.tceCampRun.map(item2 => {
                    return {
                      id: run++,
                      mypid: runheaderid,
                      pid: runheaderid,
                      rowtype: 'run',
                      expanded: false,
                      cells: [{cid: 1, text: item2.name}, {cid: 2, text: 'c 2'}, {cid: 3, text: 'c 3'}, {
                        cid: 4,
                        text: item2.id
                      }, {cid: 14}]
                    }
                  })
              },
                {
                id: run++,
                pid: j,
                header: true,
                expanded: false,
                rowtype: 'InteractiveScript',
                cells: [{ cid: 1, text: 'Interactive Script', header: false },
                  { cid: 2, text: 'Response', header: true },
                  { cid: 3, text: 'Action', header: true },
                  { cid: 4, text: 'Action Value', header: true },
                  { cid: 12, header: true  },
                  { cid: 13, header: true }],
                rows:
                  item.tceCommTreeDetail.map(item3 => {
                    return {
                      id: run++,
                      mypid: runheaderid,
                      pid: runheaderid,
                      rowtype: 'run',
                      expanded: false,
                      cells: [{cid: 1, text: item3.name}, {cid: 2, text: 'c 2'}, {cid: 3, text: 'c 3'}, {
                        cid: 4,
                        text: item3.id
                      }, {cid: 14}]
                    }
                  })

                }
              ]

          }
      }).forEach(item => other.push(item));
```

Nested rows should look like this:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

To make things easier to read and clearer, rather than doing:

```
return {
  // ...everything under the sun...
  // ...all in one long, long, list...
};
```

You should consider assigning some of the subparts of that big object to other variables before the `return`.

Then do something like:

```
if (item.tceCommTreeDetail) {
  rows = item.tceCommTreeDetail.map(item3 => {...
  ...
}
else {
  rows = []; // Or null, or whatever else you want here if item.tceCommTreeDetail is not defined.
}
```

Then:

```
return {
  // ...
  rows: rows,
  // ...
};
```

Comment: Thank you!! Simple enough! some reason I was blanking on how to combine the variables. (rows: rows ). thanks for the clarification.